# what happens if copy_to_user is in RW lock?

Tags: linux-kernel, preemption, rwlock

I implemented copy_to_user() inside read-write lock. My question is what if there is a page fault when executing the copy_to_user, will it get serviced even the lock is not released? If not, how can I achieve this? Any idea would be very appreciative.

```
read_lock(x);
copy_to_user((a), (b), (c));
read_unlock(x);
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you locking anything that page fault handler cares about?

Comment: Will the read lock disable the preemption? If so, is it possible that page fault not getting serviced as pre-emption is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Reader-writer locks are an optimized use-case of spinlocks (meant to be used in a path that has heavy reads on global/static/shared data). 
As they're essentially spinlocks, you should not put anything in their critical section that could possibly sleep (schedule()).

User page faults are a case where a sleep might occur; hence you should not do copy_[to|from]_user() in a rw-lock critical section.

What if you do?
Page faults will be disabled in any atomic context - like using rwlocks, etc. A userspace fault will cause control to vector to the fault handling code; on x86, it's here:

```
arch/x86/mm/fault.c:__do_page_fault()
...
  /*   
     * If we're in an interrupt, have no user context or are running
     * in a region with pagefaults disabled then we must not take the fault
     */
    if (unlikely(faulthandler_disabled() || !mm)) {
        bad_area_nosemaphore(regs, error_code, address);
        return;
    }
```

...

And *bad_area_nosemaphore()* would essentially kill the user process context via a SIGSEGV !

Comment: Okay, that's bad,  but what could happen if he did?

Comment: @Gilad I added this to the answer.